# Disabling vertical scrolling in UIScrollView in swift?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift

So I have my `UIScrollView`,

```
    var myScrollView = UIScrollView(frame:theFrame)
```

and I would like to disable vertical scrolling. Does anyone know how to implement this using Swift?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this. This sets the content size to the height of the frame so it disables vertical scrolling because it can display the whole size.

```
let scrollSize = CGSizeMake(theFrame.size.height, yourWidth)
myScrollView.contentSize = scrollSize
```

Answer (score 15):

Another way to do this is to set the height to 1.0

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(theFrame.size.height, 1.0)
```